# Elasticsearch curator deletes the whole index rather than deleting logs of 6 days

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I had set up the action file which was deleting 6 days data of elasticsearch using Elasticsearch Curator. But from yesterday its deleting the whole index rather than deleting data of 6 days.

```
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: >-
      Delete indices older than 6 days
    options:
     ignore_empty_list: True
     timeout_override:
     continue_if_exception: False
     disable_action: False
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: regex
      value: '^pds-cnnfr-usw2.*$'
    - filtertype: age
      source: creation_date
      direction: older
      unit: days
      unit_count: 6
```

Comment: which version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: the curator deletes indices and not the data in indices. So you can roll over the index daily and remove the index after 7 days.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/delete_indices.html

Comment: @Musban Dogan The elasticsearch version is 7.17.0 and curator version is 5.8.2

Comment: I would investigate how you were ingesting data before yesterday: your action does exactly what is expected - [deletes indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/delete_indices.html).

Comment: These are all Microservices logs , we have fluentd which accumulates the logs of eks cluster and pushed to es

Comment: Is there any issue with the version of curator ? which is causing the problem ?

Comment: I upgraded the version of curator to 7.0.0 and es version is 7.17.0

Comment: I recommend using the ILM policy rather than the curator. The curator was exist because the ILM existed on the paid version before ESv7:).
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/index-lifecycle-management.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/index-rollover.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the ILM policy rather than the curator. The curator was exist because the ILM was on the paid version before ESv7:).

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/index-lifecycle-management.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/index-rollover.html

[image]